# android touch event

Tags: android

I have two views, view A and B.

When I trigger the touch event "move" on view A, View B will show and overlay on the View A. At the same time, I want View B can receive the same touch event "move" from View A. Is it possible to send the same touch event to View B from system?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can call the `onTouchEvent()` method of viewB and pass it the MotionEvent that was given to viewA Like this:

```
viewA.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public onTouch(View v, MotionEvent me){
        viewB.onTouchEvent(me);
    }
});
```

That should pass all of the events that come to viewA on to viewB.